# Centrar un texto respeto a la pantalla con una imagen a al costado de la pantalla

Tags: html, css

Como puedo puedo poner un texto que esta alineado con una imagen que esta al costado de la pantalla, en el centro de la pantalla como lo esta "laboratorio":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
<div className="flex items-end gap-4 mb-4">
  <div className='rounded-full outline outline-4 outline-offset-2 outline-secondary-500 bg-white h-40 w-40 aspect-square relative'>
    <Image className='rounded-full' alt='' layout='fill'src={image.src} />
  </div>
  <div className="grow">
    <h2 className="font-bold text-4xl text-center">{name}</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

de tal manera que quede así, centrado pero alineado con la imagen ya sea hacia abajo o en centro de la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que esta pregunta debería tener unica y exclusivamente el tag CSS o de tailwind... el problema es solo de estilos, nada que ver con react o next.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bastaría en hacer flexible a los `div` hijos que están dentro del `div` padre para que los `div` hijos estén uno al lado del otro. Lo que hice fue agregar la clase `d-flex` de Bootstrap:

```
<div className="d-flex items-end gap-4 mb-4">
  <div class="...">
    // ...
  </div>
  <div class="...">
    // ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Y obtienes este resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora, para obtener el resultado como el de tu imagen que adjuntas, lo que hice fue que el contenido del segundo `div` hijo ocupe todo el ancho posible, con la clase `w-100`:

```
<div className="d-flex items-end gap-4 mb-4">
  <div class="...">
    // ...
  </div>
  <div class="w-100 ...">
    // ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Y obtienes el resultado esperado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código completo:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="d-flex items-end gap-4 mb-4 p-4">
  <div class='rounded-full outline outline-4 outline-offset-2 outline-secondary-500 bg-white h-40 w-40 aspect-square relative'>
    <img class='rounded-full' alt='' layout='fill'src="https://i.imgur.com/wBWzOZo.png" width="80px"/>
  </div>
  <div class="grow w-100">
    <h2 class="font-bold text-4xl text-center">Veterinarium</h2>
    <h6 class="font-bold text-4xl text-center">Laboratorio</h6>
  </div>
</div>
```